# Getting all items of one group from WebStorage

Tags: javascript, local-storage, web-storage

I want to implement simple shopping cart system on my site using WebStorage. Items are pictures with *format* and *amount* values. There is a counter value which contains the number of items available in the storage at the moment and each new item is added to WebStorage in this format:

```
item<id> = 1:3,5
```

Now I have a problem with listing items from the storage. For example, if user buys 5 items and removes `item0` and `item3` (`item -= 2`), I wouldn't be able to get all the values with simple for loop even if I check if element exists in storage:

```
var len = parseInt(localStorage.getItem("items"));
for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    if (localStorage.getItem("item" + i)) {
        // show element on the page
    }
}
```

Len will be three, but I'll still have the `item5` which wouldn't be showed.

Should I make new array of items' ID and remove ID's as items are deleted from page or there's a better way to deal with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be best to use a JSON object to handle all of your contents.

Your code would look something like this to set data:

```
// initial data
var cartData = {
    items: ['item1', 'item2', 'item3']
};

// stringify your object so it can be saved into localStorage
localStorage.setItem('cart', JSON.stringify(cartData));
```

Then you can easily remove/loop through items:

```
// get cart
var cartData = JSON.parse( localStorage.getItem('cart') );

// delete 2nd item
cartData.items.splice(1, 1);

// loop through items
for(var i = 0, l = cartData.items.length; i < l; i++) {
    // do something with cartData.items[i]
}
```